# How to enable python3 in vim?

Tags: python, ubuntu, vim

I've been using vim for some time, and now in a need to use the python3 feature.

If I type `vim --version | grep python` I get `-python3`

How can I do to enable it?

Comment: IMO this can done only on the time of compiling vim.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You didn't tell us the platform you're on, but it basically boils down to:

- Installing the prerequisite packages needed for Python 3 and for compiling Vim
- Compile Vim with the `configure --enable-python3interp` option

Comment: Hi Ingo, you're right, I didn't specified that directly, but in the tags I put ubuntu. Thanks anyway, as I've been reading, I'd say this is the only way.

Comment: Slight correction, `./configure --enable-python3interp`. The user should be able to know how to install from source, but explicitness is nice for lazy people. :)

Answer (score 4):

```
$sudo apt-get install vim-gnome
```

should take care of that but the official repos are a bit behind.

I've been using [this ppa](https://launchpad.net/~pi-rho/+ppa-packages) for a while. After you have added it to your sources, upgrading Vim should give you python 3 support. It does, here.